# Can we please merge [definition] tag into [terminology]?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Can we please merge the [definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tag into [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)?

Comment: Did you go through the questions in the definition tag? [This one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166595/common-header-file-for-c-and-javascipt) for example is about definition headers, not terminology.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Good point. I saw just one that clearly meant terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think since [definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) does not have a **wiki summary** <sup>[[here]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/definition/info)</sup> it is very easy to get confused.

Better solution IMO would be to properly define the [definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tag itself first and then let users ask question on that basis. If the tag is explained as

> Define *xxxxxx*

Then possibly [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [definition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) could be merged.